# Not able to delete document from firestore database v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a collection `users` and inside user there is a document `userID` and inside this document there is another collection `favourite` and inside this collection , there is id's of saved favourite data `favouriteId`.

So i want to delete that data inside `favourite` colletion.

My db look likes:-
`users(collection)>userID(document)>favourite(collection)>favouriteId(document)`

Here is my code for that:

```
  const deleteDoc = async (id) => {
    const userRef = collection(db, "users");
    const favRef = collection(
      userRef,
      `${firebaseAuth?.currentUser?.uid}/favourite`
    );
    const favId = doc(favRef, id);
    await deleteDoc(favId);
  };
```

*favouriteId=id* ,
*userId=firebaseAuth?.currentUser?.uid*

I use firebase v9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is Most of correct you just need  some  changings in code like  that

```
const deleteDocu = async (userId, favouriteId) => {
const userRef = collection(db, "users");
const favRef = collection(userRef, userId, "favourite");
const favId = doc(favRef, favouriteId);
await deleteDoc(favId);
};
```

Comment: Thanks bro, i solved the issue, actually the main issue is , i make my function name same as firestore funtion name. as you can see in my code.

Comment: i forget that   thanks for showing the issue i  remember that

Comment: @MAYANKTHAKUR If user JuanMalnechuk solved your problem, accept his answer as correct and give him an arrow up.

Comment: And one more thing. This is how you reference nested documents `doc(getFiretsore(), 'users/${userId}/favourite/${favouriteId}')` one line, not millions of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are naming your function in the same way as the Firebase function.

Just change the function name

```
  const deleteDocu = async (id) => {
    const userRef = collection(db, "users");
    const favRef = collection(
      userRef,
      `${firebaseAuth?.currentUser?.uid}/favourite`
    );
    const favId = doc(favRef, id);
    await deleteDoc(favId);
  };
```